# How do I do a "full rebuild" in FDT?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, build, fdt, rebuild

I switched IDEs to use FDT and want to stop the type error warnings. I went to the project's properties > FDT Problems > AS3, check "Enable project specific problems", and disabled "Function without type" and "Variable without type". This works the first time I run the project, but no subsequent times. The properties panel says "To apply these settings a full rebuild of the project is necessary!" I would like to do a full rebuild but Project > Build All is greyed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you have Project -> Build Automatically enabled, Project -> Build All will be disabled.  You need to select Project -> Clean... to clean the projects, which will kick off a rebuild.

You'll want to do a Clean anyway, to make sure everything in the project is rebuilt.